# Values do not pass when posting with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html

When posting my form it does not POST any values, but when I use GET It does.

Jquery code:

```
$('#lagg_till_kund_link').click(function() {
    $('#lagg_till_kund').submit();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.post(
        'skapa.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data){
        $('#main_content_hoger_hogerspalt').html(data)
        $('#loading').hide()
        }   
    );
    return false; 
});
```

Simple form:

```
<form method="post" id="lagg_till_kund" name="lagg_till_kund">
<input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```

Code executed on skapa.php:

```
   $insert = array();

$qry = "UPDATE kunder SET ";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    if(!empty($value) and !empty($key)) {
        $insert[] = " ".$key." = {'".$value."'}";
    }
}
$qry.= implode(', ', $insert);

echo $qry;
```

I can not find why the values won't be passed to page "skapa.php"

I have modefied the code to be as simple as possible for you to help me out. Have been strugglin with this all day. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).serialize()` probably needs changed to `$('#lagg_till_kund').serialize()`.

Comment: why do you have this: `$('#lagg_till_kund').submit();`?

Comment: To submit the form, I do not have a submit button. I submit the form from a link that is far away from the form in my html code.

Thought that was the best solution for my design.

Comment: Do you need to submit the form? I thought that was the point of your ajax $.post

Comment: Thank you Pitchinnate. Just fixed it with your critisism :)
Ofcourse I do not have to submit the form hehe when using ajax.

Took away the .submit row and change serialize as you said in your first post. 

Thank you!